# How to unit test custom console ContainerAwareCommand in Drupal 8

Tags: 8, testing, console

I have a custom console command that extends `Drupal\Console\Command\ContainerAwareCommand`. Inside the command I need to access the container to fetch a service. But now I'm struggling with figuring out how to mock the return value from the container->get command so that I can inject a stub of the actual service the command uses. So how do I set up the unit test?

The code inside the `execute()` method of my command that somehow needs to be stubbed:

```
...
$importer = $this
            ->getContainer()
            ->get('fmo.calendar.event.importer');
...
```

The unit test class so far looks like this:

```
namespace Drupal\my_module\Tests\Command\Calendar;

use Drupal\Console\Application;
use Drupal\my_module\Command\ImportCalendarEventsCommand;
use Drupal\Tests\UnitTestCase;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Tester\CommandTester;

class ImportCalendarEventsCommandTest extends UnitTestCase
{

protected $command;
protected $application;

public function setUp()
{

    $helperSetStub = $this->getMock('Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet');

    $this->command = new ImportCalendarEventsCommand($helperSetStub);

    $this->application = new Application(array('container' => $this->getContainerStub()));
    $this->application->add($this->command);
}

public function tearDown()
{
}

public function testItIsAContainerAwareCommand()
{
    $this->assertInstanceOf('Drupal\Console\Command\ContainerAwareCommand', $this->command);
    $this->assertEquals('fmo:calendar:import', $this->command->getName());
}

/**
 *
 * @param [string] arg [description]
 */
public function testCanImportCalendarEvents()
{

    $command = $this->application->find('fmo:calendar:import');
    $commandTester = new CommandTester($command);

    $code = $commandTester->execute(
        [],
        ['interactive' => false]
    );

    $this->assertEquals(0, $code);

}

private function getContainerStub()
{
    $stub = $this
        ->getMockBuilder('Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet')
        ->getMock();

    $stub->method('get')->willReturn('hello');

    return $stub;
}
}
```

But this does not work. There are new dependencies I need to mock. I tried looking through the test folder of the Drupal Console project itself, but could not find any tests for the `ContainerAwareCommand` in that project either...